# "Unicorn": what other words have this "cornus" etymology?

Tags: etymology, latin, list-request

"Unicorn" comes from the French and late Latin, with the "cornus" part meaning "horn". I am wondering what other English words share this root. I could think of "rhinoceros". Can you think of something (or multiple somethings) else?

Comment: Rhinoceros? Sure, it's the same PIE root, but from Greek rather than Latin.

Comment: The ancient Biblical Hebrew word for horn (of an animal) is "keren."
Anyone else think that may be where the Latin connection comes from?

Comment: @Faith Schames - An interesting hint. In my view there might be a connection. But there is not much to be found on the Internet about possible relations between semitic and IE words.

Comment: @FaithSchames It has been suggested and is reasonably commonly held that the Proto-Indo-European root was borrowed either to or from Proto-Semitic at some point (similar to the number seven, PIE _*septḿ_, which is almost universally considered a loan word from Semitic). Unlike with ‘seven’, though, there’s nothing unusual about the root in either language, so we don’t know which way the borrowing went.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Latin word for horn is *cornu*, stem *cornu-* (with null-inflection in the nominative case). Note that Latin *cornus*, "cornel/dogwood", comes from a different [Proto-Indo-European](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language) root and is not related. *Rhinoceros* comes from Greek *keras*, horn.

Both Latin *cornu* and Greek *keras* come from the same PIE root **ḱer-* (very frequently, and seemingly somewhat at random, expanded to **ḱerh₂-* ), which meant something like "horn, head" (note that there appear to be other PIE roots **ker-* that are not related).

The examples Snumpy and Trideceth gave all come from Latin *cornu-*. The following words come from the PIE root **ḱer-* through Latin, but not from Latin *cornu-*:

- cervix
- cerebral
- triceratops
- rhinoceros

The word *horn* comes from the same PIE root, but not through Latin: the /k/ sound was lenited to /x/ or /h/ in Proto-Germanic, as Colin Fine said, which is why we have /h/ now, just as in other Germanic languages.

Comment: The most obvious seems to be "cornet".

Comment: +1 for a very good answer. But a nitpick: /k/ did not "disappear" in Germanic (the way /p/ really did disappear in Celtic, for example) but was lenited to /x/ or /h/, just as /p/ was lenited to /f/.

Comment: @ColinFine: Ack, I knew someone would catch me! At first I had an even worse expression. Then I changed it to this, but I knew I should have looked up what happened exactly to the k, apart from the fact that it is now an h; I knew this was weak, but I was too lazy to look it up. I will incorporate your comment into my answer, if you don't mind. I figured "disappeared" might be taken as "it didn't exist after a certain time, when something else came instead of the k"; but I know that isn't the right way to say it.

Comment: To be exact, the PIE root is _*ḱer-_ (very frequently, and seemingly somewhat at random, expanded to _*ḱerh₂-_), rather than _*ker-_.

Answer (score 7):

[*cornucopia*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cornucopia)
[*corneous*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corneous)
[*corner*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corner)
[*tricorn*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tricorn)
and, believe it or not, [*corn*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/corn)

Comment: Presumably you mean a *corn* on the foot but not as in grain.  [Different roots](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=corn)

Answer (score 5):

Previous answers listed *cervix*, *cerebral*, *triceratops*, *rhinoceros*, *cornea*, *Capricorn*, *cornicen*, *corniform*, *cornucopia*, *corneous*, *corner*, *tricorn*, *corn* (on the foot), and *cornicle* as being from the same PIE root. There are others, including *hirn*, *keratin*, *kerato-* and anything formed therefrom, *cerebro-* and anything formed therefrom, many (but not all) other *corn-* and *-corn* words, and, possibly, *Cornelia*. Unrelated are *cerul-* words, *ceremony*, *karma* (related to *ceremony*, though), *hurl*, and, as someone else has mentioned, *corn* (grain).

Answer (score 3):

> **cornea
>
>   Capricorn
>
>   cornucen
>
>   corniform
>
>   cornicle**

There are many medical terms as well, which I'll not bother mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

bicorn and tricorn (as in 18th century hats)